# Dump data check failed on a TinyPICO using ESP32

Tags: serial, arduino-ide, esp32

I use the TinyPICO microcontroller with ESP32 and I program it using the Arduino IDE. I recently got a new error on my Serial Monitor:

```
E (113) esp_core_dump_�^X.K�ɕ�dump data check failed:
Calculated checksum='453aefca'
Image checksum='ffffffff'`
```

This error also occurs with the examples provided by the Arduino IDE for the TinyPICO like 'TinyPICO_Funky_LED.ino', so the error must be on the TinyPICO or must have something to do with the serial connection.

Also it is worth mentioning that this error didn't occur yesterday with the exact same computer and microcontroller. All the programs work fine but this error always comes in my Serial monitor. My guess is that I somehow accidentally wrote something on the TinyPICO which would create this error but I am not sure.

Do you have any idea on what could be the cause of this error and how I could fix it (or ignore it) ?